LEGO Answers is now Bricks
LEGO Answers has been renamed to Bricks (Stack Exchange)
Aside from the change in name, we are still the same site question and answer site for LEGO and building block enthusiasts.

It is unfortunate that a new user cannot tell from the front page what this SE is about anymore.
